# Инициализация указателей в базовом классе

Tags: c++

Возможно, вопрос глупый, но я никак не могу понять, как решить следующую проблему.
Есть класс `А`, который является базовым для классов `B` и `С`.
В классе `А` есть защищенные указатели, которые будут использоваться в наследниках.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};
protected:
    int *i;
    int *k;
    void start(){
        doSomething();
    }
    void doSomething(){
        cout<<"Test1"<<"\n";
    }
};
class B : public A
public:
    B(int *_i, int *_k){
        i = _i;
        k = _k;
    }
    ~B(){}
    void doSomething(){
        cout<<"Test2"<<"\n";
    }
    void run(){
        start();
    }

int main(){
    int i2 = 5;
    int k2 = 2;
    int *i1 = &i2;
    int *k1 = &k2;
    B b(i1, k1);
    //b.run();
    return 1;
}
```

У меня сразу два вопроса:

1. Можно ли как-то инициализировать указатели в базовом классе, чтобы в дальнейшем наследники наследовали уже готовые указатели? Сейчас у меня 5 наследников, 8 одинаковых "комплектов" указателей в каждом из них. Передавать каждый раз в конструктор эти указатели как-то некрасиво, по-моему..
2. Внутри `B::run()` вызывается `A::start()`, видимо, потому что я не переопределил `B::start()`. Можно ли как-то вызывать метод `B::start()`, чтобы он сам выполнил `B::doSomething()`, без переопределения этого метода?

Edit (более подробное описание проблемы):

```
//в конструкторе класса MainWindow:

//Algorithm::initPointers(ui->infoWidget, ui->mainLabel, ui->smallLabel, ui->progressBar, valve, pressureSensors);
emergency = new EmergencyResetOfPressure(ui->infoWidget, ui->mainLabel, ui->smallLabel, ui->progressBar, valve, pressureSensors, this);
purge = new PurgeFlowChart(ui->infoWidget, ui->mainLabel, ui->smallLabel, ui->progressBar, valve, pressureSensors, this);
fillGas = new FillingGas(ui->infoWidget, ui->mainLabel, ui->smallLabel, ui->progressBar, valve, pressureSensors, this);
strengthTest = new StrengthTest(ui->infoWidget, ui->mainLabel, ui->smallLabel, ui->progressBar, valve, pressureSensors, this);
dropPressure = new PressureDrop(ui->infoWidget, ui->mainLabel, ui->smallLabel, ui->progressBar, valve, pressureSensors, this);

/********немного из базового класса**************/
class Algorithm: public QObject //класс-родитель для всех алгоритмов
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    QLabel *ui_mainLabel;
    QLabel *ui_smallLabel;
    QProgressBar *ui_progressBar;
    QWidget *ui_infoWidget;
    Valve *valve;
    PressureSensors *pressureSensors;
    void mainLabel(const QString &text, const QString &color = NORMAL){
        emit mainLabelText(text);
        emit setWidgetColor("background-color: "+color+";");
    }
    void smallLabel(const QString &text){
        emit smallLabelText(text);
    }
    void progressBar(int value){
        if ((value >= 100) || (value <= 0))
        {
            emit progressBarVisible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            emit progressBarVisible(true);
            emit progressBarValue(value);
        }
    }
    void closeAllValves(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            valve->close(i);
    }

/********конструкторы наследников****************/
EmergencyResetOfPressure::EmergencyResetOfPressure(QWidget *ui_widget, QLabel *ui_m_Label, QLabel *ui_s_Label, QProgressBar *ui_progress_Bar,
                                                   Valve *valves, PressureSensors *pressure_Sensors, QObject *parent)
{
    ui_infoWidget = ui_widget;
    ui_mainLabel = ui_m_Label;
    ui_smallLabel = ui_s_Label;
    ui_progressBar = ui_progress_Bar;
    valve = valves;
    pressureSensors = pressure_Sensors;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(mainLabelText(QString)), ui_mainLabel, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(smallLabelText(QString)), ui_smallLabel, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(progressBarValue(int)), ui_progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(setWidgetColor(QString)), ui_infoWidget, SLOT(setStyleSheet(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(progressBarVisible(bool)), ui_progressBar, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
}
PurgeFlowChart::PurgeFlowChart(QWidget *ui_widget, QLabel *ui_m_Label, QLabel *ui_s_Label, QProgressBar *ui_progress_Bar,
                               Valve *valves, PressureSensors *pressure_Sensors, QObject *parent)
{
    ui_infoWidget = ui_widget;
    ui_mainLabel = ui_m_Label;
    ui_smallLabel = ui_s_Label;
    ui_progressBar = ui_progress_Bar;
    valve = valves;
    pressureSensors = pressure_Sensors;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(mainLabelText(QString)), ui_mainLabel, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(smallLabelText(QString)), ui_smallLabel, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(progressBarValue(int)), ui_progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(setWidgetColor(QString)), ui_infoWidget, SLOT(setStyleSheet(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(progressBarVisible(bool)), ui_progressBar, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
}
/********и так 5 раз**************/
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал конструктор с аргументами по умолчанию:

```
A(int*i = nullptr, int*k = nullptr):i(i),k(k){}
```

Вы тем самым получаете и ваше "инициализировать в базовом классе", и возможность написать

```
B(int*i,int*k):A(i,k){}
```

На второй вопрос ответ еще проще: сделайте метод виртуальным...

```
virtual void doSomething(){  // В классе A
```

Comment: Такое решение разве не для текущего экземпляра класса будет работать? Получается, если у меня будет 50 наследников, то каждому наследнику все равно придется передавать указатели в аргументах.
Edit: у меня нет проблемы передать эти указатели в базовый класс через наследников.. Проблема заключается в том, чтобы изменить сам объект базового класса, чтобы при наследовании от него дети получали уже готовые указатели

Comment: Ответ на второй вопрос оказался верным, спасибо :)
Находил уже такое решение, но по ошибке делал виртуальным метод `A::start()`, из-за чего ничего не работало.

Comment: А я что вам предлагаю? Сделайте *значения по умолчанию*. Все. Или вы хотите, чтоб у вас производный класс **ничего не передавал**, но при этом базовый **получал разные значения**? Если одинаковое - то я вам решение указал. Кстати, вы можете указать значения по умолчанию и в производном классе.

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы все наследники получили вполне конкретные указатели (указатели на QLabel'ы и т.д., если быть точным). Сейчас я это все монотонно передаю в аргументах конструкторов наследников (базовому классу они не нужны). Мне кажется, что можно эти указатели как-то в базовом классе задать, чтобы наследники получали уже все готовое.

Comment: @MaratGareev, если они не нужны базовому классу, то что он в нём делают? У Вас дизайн явно хромает. Плюс я не понимаю, чем Вас не устраивает вариант Harry, тем что нужно писать конструкторы? Этого можно не делать, просто пишите в потомках `using A::A;` (это унаследует все конструкторы `A`)

Comment: @ixSci с проектированием я на Вы, но тем не менее конкретно этот момент мне кажется логичным. Класс `А` является базовым для различных алгоритмов (потомков этого класса). У этого класса есть методы, например,     `void mainLabel(const QString &text, const QString &color = NORMAL){
        emit mainLabelText(text);
        emit setWidgetColor("background-color: "+color+";");
    }`. Наличие сигналов и слотов обусловлено работой с потоками. Эти методы для вывода текста и многое другое наследуется потомками. Внутри потомков приходится настраивать коннекты. Хотелось бы сделать это 1 раз в `А`

Comment: Еще раз - если бОльшая часть объектов должна получить одинаковые значения - используйте аргументы по умолчанию. Невозможно, не делая ничего, получить что-то разумное :)

Comment: @Harry немного дополнил пост, чтобы было понятней как сейчас все работает. Повезло, что алгоритмов всего 5, если их будет 50, например, то неужели так же придется все копипастить? И я не понимаю как мне в аргументе по умолчанию указать текущий адрес прогресс бара, например, все равно придется указатель передавать.

Comment: А сделать в базовом классе указатели статическими не вариант?

Comment: Блин, так какого черта вы передаете все это, если достаточно передать только `ui`?? Передавайте только его. Как я понимаю, сам `ui` - не константа, грубо говоря - тогда его надо передавать. Или, если это глобальная переменная - можно не передавать, а сразу в базовом конструкторе использовать эту глобальную переменную. И вообще, зачем вам в классе все эти указатели, если они уже есть в объекте `ui`? Храните в своем классе ссылку на него, и получайте указатели по мере надобности...

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Не могу сказать, что мне нравится подход с передачей кучи указателей, но раз уж есть такая система, то предложу решение, которым бы я воспользовался.</sub>

Для решение подобной задачи подходит банальная фабрика. Создадим такой класс:

```
class Factory
{
public:
    Factory(QWidget *ui_widget, 
        QLabel *ui_m_Label, 
        QLabel *ui_s_Label, 
        QProgressBar *ui_progress_Bar,
        Valve *valves, 
        PressureSensors *pressure_Sensors, 
        QObject *_parent):
        ui_mainLabel{ui_m_Label},
        ui_smallLabel{ui_s_Label},
        ui_progressBar{ui_progress_Bar},
        ui_infoWidget{ui_widget},
        valve{valves},
        pressureSensors{pressure_Sensors},
        parent{_parent}
    {

    }

    template<typename T>
    T* create()
    {
        return new T{ui_infoWidget, ui_mainLabel, ui_smallLabel, ui_progressBar, valve, pressureSensors, parent};
    }
private:
    QLabel *ui_mainLabel;
    QLabel *ui_smallLabel;
    QProgressBar *ui_progressBar;
    QWidget *ui_infoWidget;
    Valve *valve;
    PressureSensors *pressureSensors;
    QObject *parent;
};
```

В одном месте мы создаём нашу `Factory` и уже с её помощью мы будем создавать конкретные экземпляры:

```
Factory factory{ui->infoWidget, ui->mainLabel, ui->smallLabel, ui->progressBar, valve, pressureSensors, this};
emergency = factory.create<EmergencyResetOfPressure>();
purge = factory.create<PurgeFlowChart>();
```

---

И немного по самой иерархии. Вынесем всю инициализацию в основной класс:

```
class Algorithm : public QObject //класс-родитель для всех алгоритмов
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Algorithm(QWidget *ui_widget,
        QLabel *ui_m_Label,
        QLabel *ui_s_Label,
        QProgressBar *ui_progress_Bar,
        Valve *valves,
        PressureSensors *pressure_Sensors,
        QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent),
        ui_mainLabel{ui_m_Label},
        ui_smallLabel{ui_s_Label},
        ui_progressBar{ui_progress_Bar},
        ui_infoWidget{ui_widget},
        valve{valves},
        pressureSensors{pressure_Sensors}
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(mainLabelText(QString)), ui_mainLabel, SLOT(setText(QString)));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(smallLabelText(QString)), ui_smallLabel, SLOT(setText(QString)));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(progressBarValue(int)), ui_progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(setWidgetColor(QString)), ui_infoWidget, SLOT(setStyleSheet(QString)));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(progressBarVisible(bool)), ui_progressBar, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
    }
public slots:
    void setText(const QString& str)
    {
        setTextImpl(str);
    }
    //...
protected:
    virtual void setTextImpl(const QString& str) = 0;
    //...
protected:
    QLabel *ui_mainLabel;
    QLabel *ui_smallLabel;
    QProgressBar *ui_progressBar;
    QWidget *ui_infoWidget;
    Valve *valve;
    PressureSensors *pressureSensors;
};
```

Как Вы можете видеть, мы вынесли весь общий код в класс `Algorithm`, включая все слоты. Т.к. я не знаю, что у Вас должно быть в слотах, я предположил, что конкретный алгоритм имеет, что сказать по каждому слоту. Поэтому я реализовал слот `setText` в основном классе через вызов виртуальной функции `setTextImpl`, которую нужно будет переопределить в классе-наследнике.

Таким образом, класс наследник будет выглядеть так:

```
class EmergencyResetOfPressure: public Algorithm
{
public:
    // Наследуем конструктор
    using Algorithm::Algorithm;
protected:
    void setTextImpl(const QString& str) override
    {
        // Что-то делаем
    }
};
```

Вот такая идея, которую Вам необходимо будет немного допилить под свои нужды.